# Combine Different File Types into One

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a program with about 70000 files (css files,mp3 files,picture,...) in a DVD.

I want to put them to a single file(like a dll).

Is there any way to do this?

I also need their address in my application; is this possible?

Comment: "need their address in my application" - not sure what you mean here.

Comment: @Joe:i want there file address in my application

Comment: Why you want to put in one file?

Comment: @Cuong Le:my program run from dvd when i'm running it if dvd have a lot of file windows take a while to read file index but when my (70000 files)collect into one my app speed increase and i don't want to user see them

Comment: But in your question you mention *bin folder*, not *dvd*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your files in a compressed archive (like Zip or 7z).

You can use compression libraries to access the files from the archive.

Comment: my program run from DVD so when i want for example play a music from 6000 files i must unzip it to a temp folder and it take time

Comment: @irsog - Reading it off a DVD would probably take longer than decompression. And decompression can be done in memory without a temp folder (using `MemoryStream`).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create an .iso file and read it using a C# library. There are some commercial ones I found. And there should be some cost-effective options too.